# Use variables or "inject" jquery selectors when chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

is it better to do this (regarding performance, not readability...):

```
$('a.updateCartButton').click(function() {
  $('form[name=updateCartForm]').attr('action', $(this).attr('href') + '#' + $('img[id^=iconUpdateArticle]').attr('id')).submit();
  return false;
});
```

or this:

```
$('a.updateCartButton').click(function() {
  var actionHref = $(this).attr('href');
  var buttonId = $('img[id^=iconUpdateArticle]').attr('id');
  $('form[name="updateCartForm"]').attr('action', actionHref + '#' +buttonId).submit();
  return false;
});
```

Maybe someone could also explain to me how I can write a test case for something like this in jQuery Tester? Then I don't have to ask questions like this in the future... ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is fine, you're talking about the performance of variable assignment, quite possibly the fastest feature in any language. The difference between:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
return a + b;
```

versus:

```
return 1 + 2;
```

Should be close to nil for all modern day languages.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, Jake. Interesting: I would have thought that return 1 + 2 is somewhat faster than return a + b...

Comment: There are many naive JavaScript runtimes out there, so the difference *might* be measurable in your example.  However, OP's code is complex enough that I'm sure the cost of naming the local variables would be lost in the noise.

Comment: Exactly my point, feel free to mark it as the correct answer if you like ;-)